# Why is Git not push'ing a merge?

Tags: git, merge, push

I'm trying to merge [this pull request](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/478). I performed the following steps (taken directly from Bash history):

```
git checkout -b wyattoday-fix-junk-defines master
git pull https://github.com/wyattoday/cryptopp.git fix-junk-defines
git checkout master
git merge -S --squash wyattoday-fix-junk-defines
```

I tried to push with both a `git push origin master` and `git push`. In both cases Git returns:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': noloader
Password for 'https://noloader@github.com':
Everything up-to-date
```

Everything cannot be up-to-date because I merged the patch. After the change I am not seeing the code that was removed:

```
$ grep WORKAROUND_MS_BUG_Q258000 *.h *.cpp
$
```

I verified I am on Master:

```
$ git branch
* master
  noloader-master
  wyattoday-fix-junk-defines
```

Why is Git not push'ing a merge? How do I work around the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `git status` I believe you'll find that your working copy includes staged changes matching those introduced in the pull request:

```
On branch master    
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.                                 

Changes to be committed:                
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)                                   

        modified:   config.h            
        modified:   osrng.h
```

`git diff --cached` should show diffs that similarly match the PR. This is because of the [`--squash` option to `git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---squash), which doesn't actually create a new commit (my bold):

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but **do not actually make a commit**, move the `HEAD`, or record `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` (**to cause the next `git commit` command to create a merge commit**). This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

Commit those staged changes, then push.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it. The Git developers have these workflows so f**k'd up. I wish that project would hire a UX expert. They can't get it right on their own.

Comment: OK, so I did a commit and a push. Git lost the Pull Request information. Git sourced it to me instead of the fellow who took the time to make the PR. F**k'ing amazing. Another +1 to Git.

Comment: @jww, that's because it's a brand new commit. I'm curious why you used `--squash`; it sounds like you didn't really want the behaviour it gives. `git merge` without `--squash` would have (a) updated `master`, so your `git push` would have worked the first time, and (b) maintained authorship information by directly using the commit your contributor made.

Comment: We use `--squash` because we want one commit to hit the logs. Without `--squash`, Git makes an absolute mess of the logs. It even includes messages about bugs that were fixed before the commit. Its an absolute auditing nightmare. (That's speaking from experience and trying to answer auditor questions about bugs that were never in master).

Comment: Using `squah` is not the best way to manipulate the log output; you're creating a problem and then blaming git for it.  If you merge without `--squash`, you will actually have a merge (what you're doing does not produce a merge and will likely cause you additional problems down the line).  So long as you provide a meaningful commit message for the merge (and it's not git's fault if you don't), you can then say `git log --first-parent` to avoid seeing the individual commits on the "other side" of the merge.  Or you can use rebase to squash inconsequential commits together before issuing the PR